# Is there a regex to parse the values from an FTP directory listing?

Tags: ftp

I'm retrieving a list of files but the parser is breaking on one of them. So I'm going in to modify it:

RegEx:

```
/ +/g
```

Here is a listing it is having trouble with:

```
drw-rw----   2 joeUser dhapache        7 May 18  2011 Hello World.html
```

Is there a RegEx people use to parse file lists? Also, is it OK to assume that anything after the 9th position is the filename (where you are splitting on space characters?

Answer (score 2):

If possible, use `MLSD` FTP command that has a fixed format like:

```
type=file;modify=20150803062903;size=1410887680; filename.avi
```

See [RFC 3659](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3659).

Fallback to the `LIST` command only as the last resort for servers that do not support it (like IIS).

If you need file names only, use `NLIST` command. All servers do support it and it produces file names only, so no parsing is needed.

---

There's no defined format for the `LIST` command. So it's not safe to assume anything.

Particularly the IIS uses a completely different format:

```
02-11-15  03:05PM           1410887680 movie.avi
```

Even for servers that use a Unix-like format, the format will differ with age of the file. If the file is new enough, its time format will be like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp             11 Sep 09 16:00 new_file.txt
```

It's also pretty common for the user and group columns to blend together if the username is too long.

Answer (score 2):

i'm using this regex :

```
^([\-ld])([\-rwxs]{9})\s+(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\w{3}\s+\d{1,2}\s+(?:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}|\d{4}))\s+(.+)$
```

i tested that on both DART (add **r** at the start of regex) and JS and it works well.
here is the result:
https://regex101.com/r/8osTeQ/1

[image]

you can iterate like this:

```
//code in dart
String s = "drw-rw----  2 owner group 7  May 12 11:30 index.html";

Iterable<Match> matches = regExp.allMatches(s);
for (Match match in matches) {
  print("${match.group(1)}\n");//type file or dir
  print("${match.group(2)}\n");//permission
  print("${match.group(3)}\n");//nb files
  print("${match.group(4)}\n");//owner
  print("${match.group(5)}\n");//group
  print("${match.group(6)}\n");//size
  print("${match.group(7)}\n");//date
  print("${match.group(8)}\n");//file/dir name
}
```

Comment: there was an error in the regex, this is fixed: ````^([\-ld])([\-rwxs]{9})\s+(\d+)\s+(.+)\s+(.+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\w{3}\s+\d{1,2}\s+(?:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}|\d{4}))\s+(.+)$````

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd ensure that your return data is formatted to fill a given number of characters per field, padded where needed with spaces. Then my RegEx would be something like:

```
^(.*{12})(.*{3})(.*{20})(.*{20})(.*{3})(.*{12})(.*{30})
```

Where:

```
\1 = permissions
[...]
\6 = date
\7 = filename
```

Once you have the values for each match/group, trim the resulting data.

Make sense?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control of what server returns. It's for a small integrated FTP module in a larger application that users can use their own servers.

Comment: In other words, check to see if the return data is formatted to pad values with spaces so that the important data are located at the same character count for each row :)